# If I redirect my domain, will i be able to send push to my old subscribers?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker, web-push, push-api

In my website, I've been asking my users for push permission and have been sending them push notifications by using Push API.

The thing is I want to redirect my domain from "www.example.com.xy" to "www.example.com".

So, will it be still possible to send push to my subscribers which I collected once at "www.example.com.xy" ? Or am i gonna have to start fresh  and ask them for push permission again after i make the domain-redirect change?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permission and the push subscription are associated to the domain and there isn't any way to migrate to the new domain: you will have to ask permission again.